# Is GPS data already filtered?

Tags: gps, filtering

I was driving around in my car, with a GPS module on the roof. The data I collected is somewhat suspicious. The module I used is a standalone GPS module (L80-M39) integrated into a  PiHat LORA-module. I parsed the longitude and latitude coordinates from the NMEA string, and converted them to displacement coordinates from a reference point. I compared the GPS coordinates to the actual coordinates extracted from Google Maps. Here is the result:
[image: GPS vs the real route]

The difference between the GPS points and the actual location is almost 100 meters at worst. I already expected inaccuracy when using a standalone GPS module, but the surprising part is when the location is off, it is consistently off instead of being "noisy". As a side note, the horizontal accuracy (from NMEA) during the experiment was between 5-10 meters.

Is the GPS data from the module already filtered somehow, or is there another reason for consistent misplacement?

I was hoping for more noisy data to test my own filtering methods.

Comment: A CRS/datum issue is excluded?

Comment: I used Ben's answer in this thread to convert the coordinates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters
Even if there is a way to improve the overall accuracy, I assume that there should be still some noise, e.g. location varying between adjacent points. The current data looks like it is utilizing previous points and/or speed to smoothen the data IMO.

Comment: What makes you think Google maps is the true position?

Comment: I don't know anything about L80-M39, but other GPS units I've used (SiRFStar III and SiRFStar 4, u-Blox Neo6T, Neo-7P, M8-T, M8-N) all appear to be using a Kalman filter or similar - current position is dependent on previous positions rather than each position being a stand-alone solution.

Comment: @Trams, that is exactly what I have been suspecting, but official information about the filtering of the modules is really hard to find. I doubt that the filtering causes the inaccuracy in my case, but somehow I think it would be more useful for many cases that the modules would provide more "raw" data. Thus it's weird as you pointed out the filtering seems to be more like a standard than an exception.

I don't know if Google Maps is a "true position", and my reliance on it bases on the past experience in similar tasks. It is possible that there is inaccuracy caused by that.

Comment: GNSS receivers use Kalman filtering because it can give better positioning.  I've used the same survey-grade receiver with older non-kalman-filter firmware as well as with newer firmware which included kalman filter, a well-tuned filter gives significant improvement.  But a badly-set-up filter can give problems - I've seen a 3M-wide Sine wave when walking in a straight line, and SiRFStar receivers had a habit of overshooting if you drove in a straight line then went round a roundabout.  Google Maps will just get the GNSS output which will be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

That difference between Real and GPS-reported is absolutely unacceptable ***unless you're in really bad urban canyon situation***, no GNSS receiver (not even the one in your mobile phone) should give such a poor result. My experience with antique SiRFStar III and SiRFStar 4 as well as various u-blox modules from Neo-6T to M8-T is that with a halfway-decent antenna (3cm * 3cm patch or similar) you have an error of below 5-10M most of the time.  So here are a few things you could try:  First thing would be to walk around your course carrying the module, see what results that gives you.  It's possible that the L80-M39 is set up for "Walking dynamics" rather than "driving dynamics" so the filter is nailing you.  If that doesn't help, I suggest you take a step back and abandon your L80-M39 if that's an option.  Buy a u-blox M8 or similar and try that.